# FileContentResult not displaying image in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller which when called creates a filecontentresult, however when I try and set it to the source of the image, the image is not displayed. I have used firebug to debug and have seen that something is returned to the view but it looks like it does not think its valid.

The Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BespokeAnalysis(MemberModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var CostVariations = CostVariationRepository.GetAll();
            if (model.SelectedYears != null && model.SelectedTypes != null && model.SelectedCostTypes != null)
            {
                var variations = CostVariations.Where(m => model.SelectedYears.Contains(m.Year));
                variationresults = variations.Where(m => model.SelectedTypes.Contains(m.CategoryId)).ToList();
                selectedtypes = model.SelectedCostTypes.ToList();

            }
        }

return Json(new { chartUrl = Url.Action("CreateChart", "Member", new { chartType = SeriesChartType.Column, selectedtypes = selectedtypes, variationresults = variationresults }) });
    }
```

The script:

```
  $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) { 

                      $('#result').html(
                            $('<img/>', {
                                src: result.chartUrl,
                                alt: 'this is a super chart'
                            })
                        );

                    }
                });
                return false;

        });
    });
```

The view:

```
          <div id="slideleft" class="tslide">
          <div id="result"></div>
          <img id="image" src="" alt="none"/>
          @using (Html.BeginForm())
          {
          <div class="inner"><a href="#" class="toggle">Parameters</a>
             <div class="dropdowntoggle">
                <div class="buttonnarrow">Select</div>
                <div class="ui-widget-content">
                    @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.SelectedSectors, new MultiSelectList(Model.Sectors, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedSectors))                          
                </div>
             </div>
              </div>
             <input type="submit" value="Create" onfocus="this.blur()" class="createbutton"/>
          </div>
          }
       </div> 

   </div>
```

Method returning ActionResult

```
    public ActionResult CreateChart(SeriesChartType chartType)
    {
        Chart chart = new Chart();
        chart.Width = 700;
        chart.Height = 400;
        chart.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(211, 223, 240);
        chart.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        chart.BackSecondaryColor = Color.White;
        chart.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
        chart.BorderlineWidth = 1;
        chart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
        chart.BorderlineColor = Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
        chart.RenderType = RenderType.BinaryStreaming;
        chart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
        chart.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All;
        chart.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.Normal;



        foreach (var type in selectedtypes)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case 1:
                    foreach (var result in variationresults)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, double> retVal = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                        retVal.Add("Stuff1", Math.Round(result.Stuff1, 3, MidpointRounding.ToEven));
                        chart.Series.Add(CreateSeries(retVal, result.Description + type, Color.Lavender, chartType));
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    foreach (var result in variationresults)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, double> retVal = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                        retVal.Add("Stuff2", Math.Round(result.Stuff2, 3, MidpointRounding.ToEven));
                        chart.Series.Add(CreateSeries(retVal, result.Description + type, Color.Aqua, chartType));
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    foreach (var result in variationresults)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, double> retVal = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                        retVal.Add("Stuff3", Math.Round(result.Stuff3, 3, MidpointRounding.ToEven));
                        chart.Series.Add(CreateSeries(retVal, result.Description + type, Color.Azure, chartType));
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    foreach (var result in variationresults)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, double> retVal = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                        retVal.Add("Stuff4", Math.Round(result.Stuff4, 3, MidpointRounding.ToEven));
                        chart.Series.Add(CreateSeries(retVal, result.Description + type, Color.Bisque, chartType));
                    }
                    break;
                    default:
                    foreach (var result in variationresults)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, double> retVal = new Dictionary<string, double>();
                        retVal.Add("Crew Other", Math.Round(result.Crew_Other, 3, MidpointRounding.ToEven));
                        chart.Series.Add(CreateSeries(retVal, result.Description + type, Color.Lavender, chartType));
                    }
                    break;
            }


        }

        chart.ChartAreas.Add(CreateChartArea());

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
       {
           chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
           ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

           return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png", "Variations.png");
       }                      
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you using `FileContentResult` in your code? All I can see is some `CreateChart` method which you haven't shown.

Comment: Sorry Darin, The createchart returns the filecontentresult updating question now.

Comment: Shouldn't you specify the ChartImageFormat.Png upon save ? ( chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png); )

Comment: jbl, I did have that in but it did not make a difference image still displays a red cross instead of actual picture.

Comment: I guess Format is still mandatory, even though it is not the main cause of your problem. Anyway, I don't see why you need the ajax call. Just set the src of the image to the url that will produce the binary. src should be set an url, not a binary stream.

Answer (score 0):

There's way too much unnecessary noise in your question. I will try to simplify things and illustrate an example of how to use this Chart class.

I would start by writing a custom ActionResult that will render the Chart to the response instead of using some ugly MemoryStreams (that by the way you are neighter disposing, nor moving at the beginning before passing it to the `FileResult` class):

```
public class ChartResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly Chart chart;
    public ChartResult(Chart chart)
    {
        this.chart = chart;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = context.RequestContext.HttpContext;
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "image/png";
        chart.SaveImage(response.OutputStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Next we could have a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetChartUrl()
    {
        return Json(new { chartUrl = Url.Action("Chart") });
    }

    [OutputCache(Duration = 0, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
    public ActionResult Chart()
    {
        var chart = BuildChart();
        return new ChartResult(chart);
    }

    private Chart BuildChart()
    {
        Chart chart = new Chart();
        chart.Width = 700;
        chart.Height = 400;

        var series = new Series("Some stuff")
        {
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
            ChartArea = "MyArea"
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            series.Points.AddXY(i, 3 * i);
        }
        chart.Series.Add(series);
        chart.ChartAreas.Add("MyArea");
        return chart;
    }
}
```

and finally a view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetChartUrl", null))
{
    <button type="submit">Submit this form using AJAX and show chart dynamically</button>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $('#image').html(
                    $('<img/>', {
                        src: result.chartUrl,
                        alt: 'this is a super chart'
                    })
                );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>

<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: HI Darin I have tried this and it does work to the extent that it returns a blank image, the chart is not generated because the data appears to be lost when the url.action is called.

Comment: You must have done something wrong and not as shown in my answer. Let me upload my sample project so that you could test it. Just a sec.

Comment: @user329540, it looks like there's some issue with Internet Explorer (as always). I have updated my answer and renamed the Index POST controller action to `GetChartUrl` and it should work now. By the way if you want to download and try my sample application you could do so from here: http://db.tt/U26DHUbj

Comment: HI Darin, thank you I will download and give it a go later today.

Comment: Okay your example works fine but thats because you don't have any data, you are building your chart using dummy data. In my example I pass a model to my controll which then builds to lists of selected data and this is used in my create chart. If I follow your example when you call the json (Url.action.... the data is null in these lists so the chart is blank.. Hope this makes sense. Have updated question to reflect it.

Comment: But you seem to be attempting to pass some complex objects to an url: `Url.Action("CreateChart", "Member", new { chartType = SeriesChartType.Column, selectedtypes = selectedtypes, variationresults = variationresults })`. That's impossible. How do you think this will be serialized? You could store your complex data on the server (database, session, ...) and then only pass the id to your controller action: `Url.Action("CreateChart", "Member", new { chartType = SeriesChartType.Column, id = someId })` and inside the target controller action use this id to retrieve the data and build the chart.